# Adding unique elements to array conditionally inside ReactJS function

Tags: arrays, reactjs, nested

I have an react application, where a comment can have emojis attached.

I have made a function, that makes an array of emojis, and sets them to the state.

Each emoji object, has an id (name of the emoji), a count (how many times it has been added, and an author (the username if the user, who added the emoji.

As of now, I have a conditional check to see if the emoji has already been added, and if it has, the counter variable will increase instead, so only each emoji is added once. Furthermore, the array of authors is increased for each time, but I want to make it conditional, so only each author is added once.

```
addEmoji = (newEmoji) =>{
// mark if new emoji is already in the array or not
let containsNewEmoji = false;

// recreate emojis array
let newEmojis = this.state.emojis.map(emoji => {

  // if emoji already there, simply increment count
  if (emoji.id === newEmoji.id) {

    if([...emoji.authors].indexOf(this.props.comment.author.name)){ // here I'm making a conditional check to see, of the author already is added

    }

containsNewEmoji = true;
return { 
  ...newEmoji,
  ...emoji,
  count: emoji.count + 1,
  authors: [...emoji.authors, this.props.comment.author.name]
};
```

}

but do I have to return everything else again

```
  return { 
  ...newEmoji,
  ...emoji,
  count: emoji.count + 1,
  authors: [...emoji.authors]
};
```

}

this seems redundant, can this logic be improved?

EDIT:
my idea or solution so far, is to make another ocndition, where i return just the array, of there is a duplicate element of authors inside the array:

```
  if (emoji.id === newEmoji.id) {

let author = this.props.comment.author.name;
if([...emoji.authors].indexOf(author) !== -1){
  containsNewEmoji = true;
  return { 
    ...emoji,
    count: emoji.count + 1,
    authors: [...emoji.authors]
  };
}
containsNewEmoji = true;
return { 
  ...emoji,
  count: emoji.count + 1,
  authors: [...emoji.authors, author]
};
```

Comment: Returning `newEmoji` is redundant, since you are rewriting all fields with `...emoji` anyway

Comment: you're right! thanks, do you know ho wi can implement the condition?

Comment: Which condition are you looking for?

Comment: Only to add each author once

Comment: i made an edit, showing my solution so far

Comment: Except that you don't need to spread `emoji.authors` for `indexOf` operation, it looks good